# How to combine two awk commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

In my property file i do have the data like this

```
domainurl=https://example.com
abc.host=10.5.39.23#10.15.1.5
locator.port=1013#1013
db.cassandra.contactPoints=10.15.13.28,10.35.73.16,10.35.93.4
```

I do have below two commands, which are working individually fine but when i am trying to combine those commands i am not getting the expected output. Here is the commands

```
grep -P '((?<=[^0-9.]|^)[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(\.([0-9]{0,3})){3}(?=[^0-9.]|$)|(http|ftp|https|ftps|sftp)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/+#-])?|\.port|\.host|contact-points|\.uri|\.endpoint)'$file | grep '^[^#]'
| awk '/http:\/\//  {print $2,80} 
       /https:\/\// {print $2,443} 
       /Points/     {print $2,"NA"} 
       /host/       {h=$2} 
       /port/       {print h,$2; h=""}'
```

this is another command for comma separated values in excel sheet

```
awk -F"," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(i%NF==0){ORS="\n"} {if($i ~ /^\"/ || $i ~ /\"$/) {a=a OFS $i;j++;{if(j%2==0){sub(/^[[:space:]]/,X,a); print a;j=0;a=""}}} else {print $i}}}}'
```

when i combined this is final script which is **not** working as expected

```
grep -P '((?<=[^0-9.]|^)[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(\.([0-9]{0,3})){3}(?=[^0-9.]|$)|(http|ftp|https|ftps|sftp)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/+#-])?|\.port|\.host|contact-points|\.uri|\.endpoint)' abc.properties | grep '^[^#]' | awk '{split($0,a,"="); print a[1],a[2]}' | awk -F"," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(i%NF==0){ORS="\n"} {if($i ~ /^\"/ || $i ~ /\"$/) {a=a OFS $i;j++;{if(j%2==0){sub(/^[[:space:]]/,X,a); print a;j=0;a=""}}} else {print $i}}}}' | awk '/http:\/\//  {print $2,80} 
       /https:\/\// {print $2,443} 
       /Points/     {print $2,"NA"} 
       /host/       {h=$2} 
       /port/       {print h,$2; h=""}' | column -t
```

Actual output

```
http://example.com                                                                   80
 10.15.13.28                                                                         NA
10.5.39.23#10.15.1.5                                                              1013#1013
```

Expected output

```
http://example.com                                                                     80
 10.15.13.28                                                                           NA
 10.35.73.16                                                                           NA
  10.35.93.4                                                                            NA
 10.5.39.23                                                                           1013
 10.15.1.5                                                                            1013
```

Note: Comma(,) separated and hash(#) separated needs to come in the next column of csv file

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Your expected output doesn't seem to match the effort spent to find out and print e.g. the respective port numbers, or "NA" if missing. Why don't you do the entire thing in a single small `awk` script?

Comment: 1/2 I've not yet managed to work out what is actually required. You've mentioned CSV but your declared expected output isn't CSV. Or are these referring to records in your properties file? It's not clear. Does the order of the IP addresses matter? It looks like you're picking domainurl, db.cassandra.contactPoints, and then abc.host & locator.port. Is that right? In the expected output, how "big" is that whitespace per line? Is it tabs or multiple spaces, and if it's multiple spaces, how many do you want? Is the indent on line four required?

Comment: 2/2 What would be useful is for you to explain - along with your expected output - what your code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$  grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b|https.*" /tmp/test.txt
https://example.com
10.5.39.23
10.15.1.5
10.15.13.28
10.35.73.16
10.35.93.4

$ cat /tmp/test.txt
domainurl=https://example.com
abc.host=10.5.39.23#10.15.1.5
locator.port=1013#1013
db.cassandra.contactPoints=10.15.13.28,10.35.73.16,10.35.93.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to attempt to deconstruct that code to work out what it's doing, but if you care to explain it I'll see if I can amend my answer.

However the way to debug this is check the output of your pipeline at every stage to ensure its what you expect it to be.

For example, you seem to have `a | b | c` and `x | y`, and attempted to combine them as `a | b | x | y | c`. Or something.

So to find out what's not working, check the output of `a`. Then `a | b`. And then `a | b | x` . Etc.

Comment: That should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestion and answers and i have figured out how to combine using'|' symbol and this is the final code to get the expected out.

```
grep -P '((?<=[^0-9.]|^)[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(\.([0-9]{0,3})){3}(?=[^0-9.]|$)|(http|ftp|https|ftps|sftp)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/+#-])?|\.port|\.host|contact-points|\.uri|\.endpoint)' $file | grep '^[^#]'| awk '{split($0,a,"="); print a[1],a[2]}'|sed 's/^\|#/,/g'| awk '/http:\/\//  {print $2,80} 
       /https:\/\// {print $2,443} 
       /Points/     {print $2,"9042"} 
       /host/       {h=$2} 
       /port/       {print h,$2; h=""}'|awk -F'[, ]' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){print $i,$NF}}'|column -t
```